# How to implement a C++ template class with SFINAE?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

Here is my example code

```
  #include<type_traits>
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<iostream>
  
  template<
      typename T,
      typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type
      > 
  class Test{
      public:
          Test(T n1);
  };
  
  template<typename T>
  Test<T>::Test(T n1){
    std::cout << n1 << std::endl;
  }
```

All I want is to make a template class that only accepts arithmetic types for type arguments. However, the compiler throws an error with the implementation.

```
test.cpp:15:19: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Test<T>’
   15 | Test<T>::Test(T n1){
      |                   ^
test.cpp:9:7: note: declaration of ‘class Test<T>’
    9 | class Test{
      |       ^~~~
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `static_assert` sufficient?

Comment: As is, it should be: `template<typename T, typename Enabler> Test<T, Enabler>::Test(T n1)`

Comment: Note that this doesn't quite prevent you from instantiating `Test` with non-arithmetic types. While `Test<std::string>` won't compile, `Test<std::string, void>` will.